# How to de-configure flutterfire?

Tags: firebase, flutter

We connect our flutter app with firebase with the following command in CLI:

```
flutterfire configure
```

As stated in docs: *https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/*

Lets say, Now I want this app to connect with some other project present on some other Firebase console.
Then How can I de-configure my app from previous project and reconfigure with new project present?
Is their any command like this:

```
flutterfire deconfigure
```

For now I'm facing this error in console when try to reconfiguring my app with other firebase console logged in:

```
i Found 7 Firebase projects. Selecting project skillzupp-pos.
FirebaseProjectNotFoundException: Firebase project id "skillzupp-pos" could not be found on this Firebase account.
```

**Or if their is any manual way present to deconfigure my app from previos project?**

Answer (score 15):

I had to follow these steps:

1. Remove if their any default project exists in .firebaserc file.
   **Before:**

```
    {
      "projects": {
       "default": "diary-app-course"
      }
    }
```

**After**

```
    {
          "projects": {
          }
        }
```

2. Run this command in Firebase CLI:

```
firebase logout
```

3. Log in again:

```
firebase login
```

4. Again run this command in Firebase CLI

```
flutterfire configure
```

Comment: where is .firebaserc file ?

Comment: See this: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/learning-firebase-2d636.appspot.com/o/Screenshot%202022-06-05%20at%208.18.02%20PM.png?alt=media&token=43134198-500d-4a94-b8c0-367a5c0ab0a3

Answer (score 0):

On my recent project, I want to rename project name after configuration, so:

1. dart pub global deactivate flutterfire_cli
2. dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

After previous steps, I have removed project in: https://console.firebase.google.com/

3. flutterfire configure
   It will ask you about overwriting existing configuration files, I choosed Yes.

I hope it will help you.