# Firebase Emulator false check permission begin error

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-tools

I was using Firebase Emulator after configuring my pet project using Firebase and Flutterfire CLI tools for weeks, and after returning to it after few months break I'm unable to use authentication (and probably other emulator features) because of `check permission begin` error.

Im using my Redmi Note 8 Pro with Android 11 and in the past everything worked. Things I've tried so far:

1. Run `flutter clean`
2. Confirmed my AndroidManifest debug file have permissions and plain text enabled:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="obscured app name">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

3. Tried solutions from [X-Firebase-Locale thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727665/w-system-ignoring-header-x-firebase-locale-because-its-value-was-null)
4. Tried to [remove Firestore config and regenerate it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70844655/how-to-de-configure-flutterfire)
5. Uninstalled app from my device and rebuild it
6. Tried adding `usesCleartextTraffic` to main AndroidManifest even though it mustn't be there

None of above worked for me. I've run out of options and I please you to help me as this is my final and only hope to find solution to the problem.

This is log from running app and trying to register new user using email and password method.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 8 Pro in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:64987/RwhiyUBHkrE=/ws
Syncing files to device Redmi Note 8 Pro...
I/flutter ( 4474): Mapping Firestore Emulator host "localhost" to "10.0.2.2".
I/flutter ( 4474): Mapping Auth Emulator host "localhost" to "10.0.2.2".
E/ion     ( 4474): ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
I/FirebaseAuth( 4474): Creating user with to@ja.com with empty reCAPTCHA token
W/System  ( 4474): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/System.out( 4474): [okhttp]:check permission begin!
W/System  ( 4474): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out( 4474): [okhttp] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
I/System.out( 4474): [socket]:check permission begin!
W/System  ( 4474): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out( 4474): [socket] e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaUtils
E/RecaptchaCallWrapper( 4474): Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=custom_signUpPassword)with exception - A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.
I/flutter ( 4474): An unknown exception occurred.
```